# Why don't we have the power to decide if we should be born in this world or not?

Tags: islamic-basis, world

My question is going to be straight and direct because I believe in asking it instead of keeping it with me. I think answers can convince a person to a huge extent and remove all the doubts that may arise from keeping things in one's heart so please bear with me.

Islam is all about justice. If so, then why don't we, as children, have a choice about being born into this world?

Hazrat Adam(AS) defied Allah by eating in Jannah; and that resulted in him being sent to the earth. But punishing the whole humanity for it? How is that fair? One can argue it wasn't our right to begin with when we were in Jannah; but still this question comes to my mind a lot.

Why don't I have the choice to decide if I should be born into this world or not? If I absolutely have to go through it; then in many ways; somethings aren't ours to decide and how does that translate into justice?

Comment: This "punishing the whole humanity" - who told you this is what Islam believes? This is a typical Christian belief.

Comment: you or anyone, does not have a choice because not everything is in control of us. its one of the Plans of Allah... only Allah knows better that why he did not gave us choice to come into to this world. Imagine if we would be asked to come into this world, then, do you think Anyone would ever want to come into this world by his own choice?

Comment: Thankyou farhan thats a nice thought.

Burhan Khalid: No one told me anything. Its something i reached from my own conclusion.

Answer (score 3):

***Why do we as children don't have the power to decide about coming in this world?***

Simply because God willed to create human without any such power. In fact humans are forced to be born and have no option in this regard.

***Islam is all about justice.***

This is not true and should be proved first. Islam is about mercy more than justice.

***And that resulted in him being sent to the earth.***

This is not true in Islam. Perhaps you have taken this belief from the current distorted Christianity. God decided to have a Caliph on earth so sent human to earth. This the reason for sending human to earth. Not what you said.

> And [mention, O Muhammad], when your Lord said to the angels,
>   **"Indeed, I will make upon the earth a Caliph."** They said, "Will You place upon it one who causes corruption therein and sheds blood,
>   while we declare Your praise and sanctify You?" Allah said, "Indeed, I
>   know that which you do not know." http://tanzil.net/#2:30

Understanding the concept of "Caliph of God on earth" is not easy and it can be asked in another question.

***But punishing the whole humanity for it?***

What punish?! Worldly life is not a punish at all. But it is a great opportunity for human for knowing and meeting God and becoming like God. Forget the beliefs of distorted Christianity.

> O mankind, indeed you are laboring toward your Lord with [great]
>   exertion **and will meet it**. http://tanzil.net/#84:6

Please note all humans will not meet God.

Being in Jannah is not a right for human so not being in it is not an injustice at all. It is mercy of God. Not right of human.

Comment: Thank you @Battle-of-karbala for your useful answer. I reckon it can be an appropriate answer for the mentioned question.